# Make ElementID value equal another Element's value

Tags: javascript, forms, getelementbyid

I'm sure this is very simple.

How can I make a form elementID value equal another element's value using Javascript?

I've got something like this:

```
document.getElementByID("_1_1_35_1_Name").value = document.getElementByID("_1_1_120_1").value
```

Comment: please, pay attention to to registry. It is getElementById, not getElementByID. It might be the reason why it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign the value:

```
document.getElementById("_1_1_35_1_Name")
   .value = document.getElementById("_1_1_120_1")
   .value = 'your value';
```

And check case for ID should be Id.

Comment: I changed it to

    document.getElementById("_1_1_35_1_Name")
   .value = document.getElementById("_1_1_120_1").value

However, I'd also like to know how I do this:
document.getElementByName("_1_1_35_1_ID")[0]
   .value = document.getElementById("_1_1_120_1").value

Comment: getElementsByName not getElementByName

Answer (score 0):

```
var newvalue = document.getElementByID("_1_1_120_1").value;
document.getElementByID("_1_1_35_1_Name").value = newvalue;
```